# Boot from a mounted .ISO?

Tags: iso

My installation of Ubuntu on my Poweredge is very messed up. I need to reinstall Ubuntu, but my CD-Drive is broken, and these machines don't boot off of USB's! Is there any way I can mount Ubuntu 12.04 as an ISO and boot off of that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MEMDISK](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/MEMDISK) to boot from the .iso image using your existing bootloader.

Comment: My computer shows that I have syslinux installed, but how would I use it to boot from the .iso ?